# Manifest merging in Android Studio

Tags: android, merge, android-manifest, android-studio

Is there any way to use ADT's manifest merging feature (manifestmerger.enabled=true in project.properties) in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. create sample project**

[image]

**2. add new module**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**3. Module Setting**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**4. Remove files in App Module**

> Move app/~~~/values/style.xml  to common/~~~/values/style.xml

[image]

[image]

edit 1.

```
<!-- app/~~~/AndroidManifest.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kr.mymy.manifestmergerforandroidstudio" >
 
    <application >
        <activity
            android:name="kr.mymy.common.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
 
</manifest>
```

edit 2.

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">  <!-- add this line -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
 
</manifest>
```

edit 3.

```
package kr.mymy.common;
 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
   
   
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
   
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
     
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

[image]